# How do I submit a form in javascript using the getElementsByName method?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyname

I'm just curious about a certain scenario:

If I want to submit a form using getElementById using the following code below:

```
 document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
```

it works fine. However, trying similar code using getElementsByName in the code below:

```
document.getElementsByName("form_name").submit();
```

doesn't work, although there is only a single element with this name: form_name.

**So my question is?**

Is it possible to submit a form using getElementsByName, or do I need to give an id to all of my forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName` returns an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName), so you need to access it with the array index notation:

```
document.getElementsByName("form_name")[0].submit();
```